# Hibernate Stored Procedure returning same value for multiple calls

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures, hql

I have a stored procedure which returns me more than one result set. The output varies for different inputs to the stored procedure.

When I call the stored procedure separately (2 runs) with different inputs, it is returning as expected.

When I call them twice withing a same method,it is returning the same value.

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
              name = "getFees",
              query = "call SCHEMA1.RES_FEES(:id,:type,:orig,:dest)",
              resultClass = Fees.class)
```

For ex: id=1, type="R", orig="Vegas" dest="London" it returns fee to be $100
for id=2, type="V", orig="London" dest="Vegas" it returns fee to be $90

When i execute the SP with with ip1 separately it returns $100
When i execute the SP with with ip2 separately it returns $90

But when i execute the SP twice withing a same method in JAVA with different sets of input, it returns $100 twice.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Weird problem. Here are few suggestions and tests that you can do to debug the issue.

1. Switch on the query log of hibernate and see if there any abnormal thing.
2. Check if you are using  second level caching in your application. If yes disable it and run your test again to see if there is any issue with caching.